# Laravel search by (variable number of) multiple keys

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a moderately complex search form:

[SEARCH FORM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/di46u8srnn70bq5/job-listings.png)

My need is to be able to accept any combination of these fields and return the corresponding list of Posting objects. Short of dropping out of Eloquent and writing the SQL conditionally, how should I go about building the selection up *conditionally*.

```
if( !empty($library_type_id))  // query gets a library_type_id where clause added
if( !empty($province_id))  // query gets a province_id where clause added
etc.
```

The table layout is simplified over my earlier version:

```
Posting->profile->library_type_id
Posting->profile->org_name
Posting->profile->province_id
```

I have been given a couple of suggestions in the past week which are not working out. At the moment I have a SearchServiceProvider which consists in the following lines:

```
<?php namespace BCLA\Search;

use Posting;
use Profile;
use Input;
use DB;

class Search {

public function posts()
{
    $type_id  = Input::get('type_id');
    $org_name = Input::get('org_name');
    $province_id = Input::get('province_id');
//    $city     = Input::get('city');
//    $keywords = Input::get('keywords');

    $profiles = DB::table('profiles')
                ->select(DB::raw('id'))
                ->where('library_type_id','=',$type_id)
                ->where('org_name','LIKE',"%$org_name%")
                ->where('province_id','=',$province_id)
                ->get();

    dd($profiles);

    $posts;
    return $posts;
}
}
```

At the `dd($profiles);` I consistently get an empty object, even when all the where clauses resolve to valid values.  I have only a handful of records in the db, so I am sure my search inputs are valid.

Any thoughts on how I should proceed appreciated.
- Erik

Comment: You can always add `->toSql()` after `->get()` to see the query, maybe there is some problem.

Comment: `Input::get(..)` returns `null` if you happen to have any of the request vars not set, so obviously query won't return any rows (unless there are `null` values in the db, which I suppose is not the case). @delmadord better is to use `DB::getQueryLog()` since it shows all the queries. Or you can use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. However `->toSql()` won't work on `get()`, becuase the latter returns a collection.